# sql table to update nulled column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Table like given below

```
Id         country       Person        Money     sum

1           UK           john          2010      null
2           USA          Henry         120       null
3           RUS          neko          130       null
4           GER          suka          110       null
7           CAN          beater        1450      null
8           USA          lusi          2501      null
```

each money column multiply by 2 and that stored into corresponding sum column how, like given below

```
Id         country       Person        Money     sum

1           UK           john          2010      4020
2           USA          Henry         120       240
3           RUS          neko          130       260
4           GER          suka          110       220
7           CAN          beater        1450      2900
8           USA          lusi          2501      5002
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759300/sql-table-how-to-multliply-array-of-numbers-fetched-from-sql-table-and-stored-in?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to update the field using an expression like this.

```
update `tablename` set `sum` = `Money` * 2 where `sum` is null;
```

If you want this to happen indescriminately you can drop the where portion of the update like:

```
update `tablename` set `sum` = `Money` * 2;
```